# FFmpeg: Masking webcam while recording

Tags: ffmpeg, mask

I hope you're all having a great day.

I'm trying to record a webcam that is shaped as a rounded-rectangular on the top-right of the screen.

[I'm using this mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2fYs.png)

The shape of the webcam in the video is actually the same as the mask but the problem is that it can only record the first frame then the webcam freezes until the end of the video.

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -s 1360x768 -framerate 30 -i desktop 
       -f dshow -i video="webcam-device":audio="audio-input-device" 
       -filter_complex "movie='roundedrectangle.png',alphaextract[a];[1:v][a]alphamerge,scale=256:-1[cutout];[0:v][cutout]overlay=10:10,split=2[output0][output1]" 
       -map 1:a -c:a aac -map "[output0]" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2M -preset fast -s 1280x720 -f mp4 output0.mp4 
       -map 1:a -c:a aac -map "[output1]" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2M -preset fast -s 1280x720 -f mp4 output1.mp4
```

Expected output: Two videos with sound that got a rounded-rectangular webcam on the top left of the screen.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alphamerge terminates with the shortest input and your 2nd input is a single frame. So you need to loop it.

```
movie='roundedrectangle.png':loop=0,alphaextract[a];
```

Comment: Good lord this is the third time you help me out, I'm feeling embarrassed :') Thank you so much